# Disabling a spinner depending on the position of the other spinner

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, spinner

I am making some UI as an intern.
however i ran into a problem, Note that im very new to kotlin.

If i pick a program or "My part" in the first spinner then the second spinner should be enabled again + if no program is selected there should also be shown a textview with a warning.

UI image is added for clarification[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbpt6.png)

spinner XML + textview for warning

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/partSpinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:entries="@array/SpinnerDriveScrew"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/secondSpinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:entries="@array/SpinnerDriveScrewSecond"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noneSelectedMarking"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/warningicon"
        android:text="no programs available/selected" />
```

and the fragment code.

```
 private val list = arrayOf("..","My part","..","..")
    override fun onCreateView(

        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val spn =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drive_screw, container, false)
        val spinner = spn.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.partSpinner)
        val secondspn = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drive_screw, container, false)
        val spinnertwo = secondspn.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.secondSpinner)
        val warning = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drive_screw, container, false)
        val warningmsg = warning.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noneSelectedMarking)
        spinnertwo.isEnabled = false

        warningmsg.isVisible = false


        spinner?.adapter = activity?.applicationContext?.let {
            ArrayAdapter(
                it,
                com.google.android.material.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                list
            )
        } as SpinnerAdapter
        spinner?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

            override fun onNothingSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                if(position == 0){
                    warningmsg.isVisible = true

                }
                if(position == 1){
                    spinnertwo.isEnabled = true
                    warningmsg.isVisible = false

                }
                if (position == 2){
                    warningmsg.isVisible = true
                }
                if (position == 3){
                    warningmsg.isVisible = true
                }


            }


        }
        return secondspn
```

Searching google, youtube, and stackoverflow